# Dask get_dummies Does Not Transform Variable(s)

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dummy-variable

I'm trying to use `get_dummies` via `dask` but it does not transform my variable, nor does it error out:

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_d = dd.read_csv('/datasets/dask_example/dask_get_dummies_example.csv')
>>> df_d.head()
   uid gender
0    1      M
1    2    NaN
2    3    NaN
3    4      F
4    5    NaN
>>> daskDataCategorical = df_d[['gender']]
>>> daskDataDummies = dd.get_dummies(daskDataCategorical) 
>>> daskDataDummies.head()
  gender
0      M
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      F
4    NaN
>>> daskDataDummies.compute() 
  gender
0      M
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      F
4    NaN
5      F
6      M
7      F
8      M
9      F
>>>
```

The `pandas` equivilent (run in a new terminal just in case) is:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_p = pd.read_csv('/datasets/dask_example/dask_get_dummies_example.csv')
>>> df_p.head()
   uid gender
0    1      M
1    2    NaN
2    3    NaN
3    4      F
4    5    NaN
>>> pandasDataCategorical = df_p[['gender']]
>>> pandasDataDummies = pd.get_dummies(pandasDataCategorical)
>>> pandasDataDummies.head()
   gender_F  gender_M
0       0.0       1.0
1       0.0       0.0
2       0.0       0.0
3       1.0       0.0
4       0.0       0.0
>>>
```

My understanding of [this resolved issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1581) is that it should work, but is it required to be pulled into `pandas` first? If so it defeats the purpose of me using it since my datasets (~500GB) won't fit into a `pandas` dataframe. Am I misreading this? TIA.

Comment: You don't need a list to select a column : `df_d[['gender']] `-->`df_d['gender']`

Comment: the real example (existing code) is 200+ variables

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to convert your column of strings to a `Categorical` before trying to use `get_dummies`. [This pull request](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1602) added a `dask.dataframe.get_dummies`, which *will* error if you try to pass `object` (string) columns, unlike `pd.get_dummies`.

To get a `Categorical` you can either use `.categorize` before `dd.get_dummies`, or with pandas >= 0.19, use read in your CSV with the `dtype` keyword like

```
df_d = dd.read_csv('/datasets/dask_example/dask_get_dummies_example.csv', dtype={"gender": "category"})
```

Here's a small example:

```
In [2]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [3]: bad = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']}), npartitions=2)

In [4]: bad.head()
/Users/tom.augspurger/Envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dask/dataframe/core.py:3699: UserWarning: Insufficient elements for `head`. 5 elements requested, only 3 elements available. Try passing larger `npartitions` to `head`.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(n, len(r)))
Out[4]:
   A
0  a
1  b
2  a

In [5]: dd.get_dummies(bad)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-651de6dd308c> in <module>()
----> 1 dd.get_dummies(bad)

/Users/tom.augspurger/Envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dask/dataframe/reshape.py in get_dummies(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na, columns, sparse, drop_first)
     68         if columns is None:
     69             if (data.dtypes == 'object').any():
---> 70                 raise NotImplementedError(not_cat_msg)
     71             columns = data._meta.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns
     72         else:

NotImplementedError: `get_dummies` with non-categorical dtypes is not supported. Please use `df.categorize()` beforehand to convert to categorical dtype.

In [7]: dd.get_dummies(bad.categorize()).compute()
Out[7]:
   A_a  A_b  A_c
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    0    0    1
```

Dask requires categoricals for `get_dummies` because it needs to know all of the new dummy-variables it needs to create. pandas doesn't have to worry about this since all of your data is already in memory.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply and that makes sense. While your example works adding the .categorize() to my example gives me: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'categorize'

Comment: You should be able to `dd.get_dummies(data.to_frame().categorize())`

Comment: sorry, that gives me this error: `raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'`

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same code in both places? Your first comment had an issue because you had a series instead of a DataFrame; your second comment has an issue because you have already have a dataframe.